# How to Change Font Color with XSLT?

Tags: xslt

i would like to change the font colour of my title(i managed to give it a black background) into white. I figured i would make a font tag around it, which didn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated(don't blame me, i am a newbie. And yes, i googled first)

```
<tr bgcolor="#000000">
       <font face="courier" color="white">
        <th>Black Components</th>
       </font> 
</tr>
```

It appears as a Black window with a black font in it

as a little bonus, if someone could tell me how to change the font style too, that would be amazing

Answer (score 2):

Inside your table or another part of pdf you can use

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" color="#ffffff"> your text or somethig else </fo:block>
```

Answer (score -1):

In modern HTML, it is preferred to use CSS stylesheets instead of things like a `bgcolor` attribute or a `font` tag, as those are considered obsolete. The following should help you:

```
<tr style="background: black;">
    <th style="color: white; font-style: italic; font-family: Courier, monospace;">Black Components</th>
</tr>
```

Professional websites also usually encapsulate such styles into classes so that you don't need to copy these attributes all the time. This would look like:

```css
/* CSS file, e.g. main.css */
.row { 
    background: black;
}

.column-header {
    color: white; 
    font-style: italic; 
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML file, should reference main.css with a <link> tag inside <head> -->
<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="column-header">Header 1</th>
        <th class="column-header">Header 2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See also [MDN documentation about CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).

Comment: i am working with xml and xsl, not with html and css

Comment: there ain't no colors in xml and xsl at all. You can only see them when you use html and/or css.. Your `<tr>` is a html table row.

Comment: Econ, as @Stefan Hegny said, XML/XSL is not a visual rendering technology, the HTML/CSS is. It works like that: an XML file with data is passed to XSLT processor that uses a template to produce HTML.